# As I research a question that I asked, is it appropriate to answer my own question multiple times?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

Here is a question where I had posted separate answers to my own question:

[Can I semi-automate MCMC convergence diagnostics to set the burn-in length?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4258/1381)

But then was requested to combine them. Which is this the preferred approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion on this issue:

I think you should provide only one answer. I cannot think of a reason to do otherwise. You can always split up the answer into sections such as "Method 1", "Theoretical Solution", "Illustrative Code" etc.

Comment: The reason I might do otherwise is to find out which one is voted 'best' by public opinion

Comment: The only exception is when you cast two opposite answers, so that they should be separated in light of voting. The only example I know is one of does-oil-prevent-pasta-from-sticking questions on SeasonedAdvice: http://seasonedadvice.com/questions/3994/does-oil-in-the-boiling-water-prevent-the-spaghetti-from-sticking-together-clos

Comment: @David @mbq If you have to appeal to public opinion to decide the best answer then it suggests that there is no objective 'correct' answer as neither answer stands on its own merit. In such a case, I think the competing answers must be made CW.

Comment: @Sirkant. a) what is 'CW' b) Each of my answers has clear pros and cons, and I have found one that suits my needs for the present, but my goal would be to receive feedback on the pros and cons of each. On the other hand, the reason I asked this question is that it felt 'awkward' to make so many separate posts. I'd prefer that someone expand on the different ideas that I have presented.

Comment: @David CW=community-wiki (no unique answer, no rep gained); the reason why I suggested to merge all your responses into a single one was that it was not clear whether (a) you're expecting an answer from others, and (b) we have to vote up every answer although some appear clearly linked -- commenting each of your answer, on the other hand, would not resemble a wiki anymore, but rather a chat session (IMO).

Comment: Thanks @chi, I didn't realize the distinction, and it was the CW format that I was following. Thanks for pointing that out.